# Upload things to a FTP in Objective-C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, upload, ftp

Some days ago I was asking how to download files from a FTP and I solver my problem with NSData and dataWithContentsOfURL of this kind:

`ftp://user:pass@server/path/of/file.extension`

But now I need to upload a file, and I was wondering if there is any instruction to upload files through an URL but I think it could not be possible and many many libraries I saw for iOS use PHP and I don't want it, and SimpleFTPSample from Apple is so confusing for junior developers that I could not understand nothing, so a simple code to upload a file specifying URL, Path, File, user and pass?

Comment: Try here.  http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-objc.asp

Comment: That's not a free library... Thanks

Comment: I only have the FTP to store thing online

Comment: I sincerely hope you are using *some kind* of on-the-wire encryption.  That URL would normally cause the username/password to be sent in the clear and be easily sniffable.  FTP is generally a security nightmare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like an easy library I would recommend using HTTP and the AFNetworking library.

However if you want to do FTP, Apple provides step by step instructions. It is a bit hairy, so I recommend just copy and pasting and tweaking as necessary. You will have to read the docs a tiny bit. Look for the "Uploading a File" section.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html

This should help with the initial part that apple does not provide the code for

```
CFStringRef url = CFSTR("ftp://ftp.somedomain.com/file.txt");
CFURLRef requestURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, url, NULL);

CFReadStreamRef readStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestURL);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: With CFSTR cannot make a dynamic string, right? I cannot `CFSTR(path)` just with literal strings?

Comment: CFString is “toll-free bridged” with its Cocoa Foundation counterpart, NSString...which means you can create the string dynamically with NSString (assuming you are more familiar with it) and then assign it like so:  CFStringRef url = (__bridge CFStringRef)(SOME_NSString)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Apple Simple FTP Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html). All you need is there.

If you are looking for a Framework have a look at the [ConnectionKit project](http://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit/).

Comment: I know buy my question is for other alternative :(

Answer (score 3):

[BlackRaccoon](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon) is a good, free, open source library for doing FTP transfers.

Comment: I had a poke around — as the author doesn't state it — this is a wrapper around CFNetwork's FTP functionality