# Downloading from FTP server iOS 7

Tags: ios, ftp

I have tried this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:ftpURL];    
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];            
if (data){
   [data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:(YES)];
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work... I have initialised `dataPath`, and `ftpURL` elsewhere..I know they aren't null. And `data` just returns null for some odd reason.

Does the above method support FTP download?

I have also searched on Google and StackOverflow regarding this and I couldn't find a solution that would help me.
I saw SimpleFTPSample and I thought the above method was easier.

Comment: Have you tried using dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: and looking at the NSError return?

Comment: @neilco I thought upload and download where different?

Comment: @mjswan No, let me try that... Thanks

Comment: @user959631 The [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14484610/24073) shows how to download via FTP.

Comment: Turns out that my `url` is returning null too. I checked `ftpUrl` and that definitely isn't null. Weird.

Comment: @neilco Wow, I completely missed that. God I am so tired. Sorry for that =]

Comment: Ok, so how would I write the `readStream` to file? `CFStringRef url = CFSTR("ftp://ftp.somedomain.com/file.txt");
CFURLRef requestURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, url, NULL);

CFReadStreamRef readStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestURL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out my problem, NSURL was returning null because I needed to `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` my `ftpURL` string.

Thanks guys for the help anyway =]